# Most efficient way of authorizing users over different pages on my site?

Tags: session, authorization

I have only ever made single page webapps in the past; with these, as soon as a user connected, I would read the password hash stored in their cookies and match it to the value stored in my database to determine if the user was already logged in.

I am now wanting to make a site with multiple web pages though, and I have just realized that it would required querying the database *every* time a user goes to a new page; this seems extremely inefficient to me. Is there any better way to maintain an ongoing session with a client without straining my database/server in the process?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ I'm using Node.js; it shouldn't matter though, should it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using a session object Eg HttpContext.Session["UserAuth"] = true;

When you authenticate the user on your first page Eg Login, you can then create a session like  in the example above. Then once you redirect to the next page, just check to see if the session does indeed exists and is valid.

Checking session:

> ```
>    if(HttpContext.Session["UserAuth"] != null)
>    {
>      if(HttpContxt.Session["UserAuth"].toString() == "true")
>      {
>         //Session is valid and user is logged in.
>      }
>      else{
>        //Session is invalid and user is not logged in.
>          }
>    }
> ```

So each page you want to check if the user is valid you can do the above check. As long as you have created the session on the first page at time of database authentication.

Please note the above code is just to give you an idea of how you can do this.

---

"UserAuth" is simply a the name you give to the Session that you are storing. It can be absolutely anything. The value you are storing in the Session in this case is 'true'.

So when you retrieve the value of the Session you simply get 'true', meaning the user is logged in.

When you log the user out for example you can change the value of the session "UserAuth" to false in the same manner in which you originally created it.

Eg

> HttpContext.Session["UserAuth"] = false;

Comment: And what would the userauth be? A randomly generated hash?